# Unexpected behavior in dropdown list with setDataValidation

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote this function do insert a dropdown list in non used cell of my spreadsheet:

```
function insertDropdownList(folderID){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var options = [];
  Logger.log("options = " + options);
    var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(folderID);
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    for (var i in files) {     
        var item = files[i].getName(); 
      Logger.log("item = " + item);
        options.push(item);
    }
    Logger.log("options2 = " + options);
    var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, getColumnNrByName(sheet, "COLUMN NAME")+1, sheet.getMaxRows());
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(options, false).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule); 
}
```

But despite the `options` array is ok, with the expected content, the dropdownlist inserted in the cells are splited according with the commas in the files title. These files:

[image]

Became this dropdownlist (where Larry Page name is splited into another item, instead of be part of the two names):

[image]

I've tried something like this: `options.push([item]);` and `"Larry Page, on Why Moon Shots Matter"`. But nothing worked. How to fix this?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInList%28String,Boolean%29):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you are going to be able to keep the comma in your options list.  There is no escape character for commas in javascript.  And your options array ends up as a single string that is then split with the comma as the delimiter.  The easiest way to visualize what is going on is to look at the data validation through the UI.

[image]

The easiest workaround would be to replace the comma with another separator.
E.g.

```
 var item = files[i].getName().replace(',',' -');
```

[image]

The other way I would think to go about this, which is closer to what you are looking for, would be to populate your list of file names in a hidden column / sheet, and use .requreValueInRange.  This gives you your proper formatting with the commas in tact.

[image]

```
function setList() {
  try{
   var folderId = '0B899iW4paMb-RUGUdHRtYzJwQTQ';
   insertDropdownList(folderId);
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}


function insertDropdownList(folderID){
  try{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
    // use fileRange to store list of file names for validation selection
    var fileRange = sheet.getRange("K1");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var options = [];
    var r = 0;  // counter for rows when populating file list from Drive
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while(files.hasNext()){
        var item = files.next().getName(); 
        fileRange.offset(r,0).setValue(item);
        r += 1;
    }
    var fileListRange = sheet.getRange("K1:K" + (r+1));
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow,1);
    var rule =       SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(fileListRange,false).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule); 
    sheet.hideColumn(fileListRange); // hide the validation column
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Cyrus. That isn't the best solution for my needs, but it help me to think one. I'm thinking about using `regex javascript` to get back the commas (which I need, because the items will be inserted as a string in a template).

Comment: I added another solution to my answer that allows you to maintain the commas.  The trade-off is that you'll have to store the file list on the Google Sheet somewhere.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing comma with `&#44;`